# Kivy - Audio Management

Tags: android, audio, kivy

I'm trying to use my sound files in my apk. But i have many sound files and i loading'em at the begining like that:

```
def on_pre_enter(self):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.load_sound_files)
...
... 
def load_sound_files(self,*args):
    self.bg_music = Soundloader.load('1.wav')
    self.sound1 = Soundloader.load('2.wav')
    ... 
    ...
```

After this use, im waiting about 15-20 seconds to start apk on mobile.I changed my .wav files to .ogg .The result was same. Is there any advice to use new format or load these sounds quickly somehow. I need to reduce this loading time..

[Note: 1.wav about 23mb  ,  1.ogg about 2mb. But result is same ?]

Comment: On a technical level, they can probably be packed and accessed more efficiently in the apk, but python-for-android doesn't really expose that. It wouldn't be a simple solution right now.

Comment: Using `Clock.schedule_once()` loads all the files on the main thread, so the App will be frozen until all the files are loaded. Consider loading the files on another thread. Or maybe only load the barest minimum of sounds on the main thread.